# Access button in radgridview during RowLoaded

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have Simple radgridview.
In Last column I have radbutton

I want to access this radbutton during grid loaded

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="gvViewer" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

<telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="StatusName" Width="200">

                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="StatusName" />
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.Header>

                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <telerik:RadButton Name="btnSend" Content="Send" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>

</telerik:RadGridView>
```

I have this event rowLoaded

```
void gvViewer_RowLoaded(object sender, RowLoadedEventArgs e)
{
            var button= row.ChildrenOfType<RadButton>();
}
```

row.ChildrenOfType() returns null to "var button"

How do i access this button?

Comment: Why not set `Loaded` handler on Button itself? Also check if your scenario can be accomplished with just bindings, it will be more SL-like.

Answer (score 0):

Please try checking this way  Row.FindControl("btnSend");  Or
e.Row.FindControl("btnSend");  and cast as RadButton for using it